# Get script path of the current ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does a method exist in asp.net to get the script path without the filename. For example if the url of my asp.net page is http://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/mypage.aspx, does a method exist that returns '/folder/subfolder/'? Right now, I do it like this:

```
myPath=mid(Request.Path,1,instrrev(Request.Path,"/"))
```

But I wonder if this custom function is needed.

Comment: Did you try `Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.Split('/');`

Comment: Split the url by the '/' delimiter, and return an array, if I understand it right? That would be something different than what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var fileName = new FileInfo(Request.ServerVariables["PATH_TRANSLATED"]).Name;
var folderPath = Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"].Replace(fileName, string.Empty);
```

Comment: That is more straightforward than my solution, but the answer would be: no, there is no (build in) method to get that specific part of the path. Besides, I wonder if there is any difference between `Request.ServerVariables['PATH_INFO']`, `Request.ServerVariables['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `Request.Path`.

Comment: Nope, there is no server variable with that. Though this is old, this list is still valid http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/servervariables.asp